# How do I import ReactJS as a module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module, es6-modules

I feel really stupid about now.  I'm using a module:

```
<script type="module" src="./app.js">
```

That module tries to import React:

```
import React from "./react.production.min.js";
```

But this results in:

```
The requested module 'react' does not provide an export named 'default'.
```

What's the right way to use react in a module?

Note that serving this from nextjs (or other similar ideas) is not feasible as this is an embedded application which doesn't have the spare capacity to spin up a nextjs instance.

Edit: I've also tried:

```
import * as React from './react.production.min.js';
```

The import succeeds but trying to use it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
```

produces:

```
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

Comment: Have you tried `import * as React ...`?

Comment: Yes.  The import succeeds then, but trying to refer to anything in the module doesn't - eg `class MyComponent extends React.Component {` gives `Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or nil`.

Comment: `nextjs` is not a bundler for react. Do you want to develop the website on an embedded machine? Why don't you just copy the output files onto it?

Comment: @Konrad that is, more or less, what I'm doing (with a babel stage to translate JSX).  But if my JS is written as modules, how do I import React in that type of deployment?  Per the question, it doesn't work.